# Spring Security - how can I define intercept-url dynamically using Database?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've been working on a spring security recently and I need to know how I can define intercept-url (in Spring Security) dynamically using a Database.

I've already dug deep the whole internet and I could not find any unique (and of course useful) tutorial in this area.

So here is what I did:

---

First I implemented FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource Abstract class:

```
public class MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {


    public List<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) {
        FilterInvocation fi = (FilterInvocation) object;
        String url = fi.getRequestUrl();
        List<ConfigAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<ConfigAttribute>();

        attributes = getAttributesByURL(url);

        return attributes;
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public List<ConfigAttribute> getAttributesByURL(String inputUrl)
    {
        List<ConfigAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<ConfigAttribute>();

        Connection connection = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://173.0.0.22:3306/";
        String dbName = "kheirkhahandb";
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "kheirkhahan";
        String password = "kheirkhahan";
        try{
            Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, userName, password);
            try{
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                String selectquery = "select * from URL_ACCESS where URL = '" + inputUrl +"'";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectquery);
                while(rs.next()){
                    MyConfigAttribute temp = new MyConfigAttribute();
                    String attr = rs.getString("ACCESS").toString();
                    temp.setAttr(attr);
                    attributes.add(temp);
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException s){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return attributes;
    }
```

---

and I set my security.xml as:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                filters="
            securityContextPersistenceFilter,
            logoutFilter,
            authenticationProcessingFilter,
            exceptionTranslationFilter,
            filterSecurityInterceptor" />
        </sec:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
        <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp?error=entryPoint" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
        <property name="errorPage" value="/login.jsp?error=access_denied" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
        <property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="myFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource" class="com.datx.dao.MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource">
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoutFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="/login.jsp?error=logout" />
        <constructor-arg ref="logoutHandler">
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoutHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"></bean>
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                group-authorities-by-username-query="
                                        SELECT acg.ID, acg.GROUP_NAME, a.AUTHORITY_NAME AS AUTHORITY 
                                        FROM ACCESS_GROUPS acg, ACCESS_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP agm, GROUP_AUTHORITIES ga, AUTHORITIES a
                                        WHERE agm.USERNAME = ? and acg.ID = ga.GROUP_ID and acg.ID = agm.GROUP_ID and ga.AUTHORITY_ID = a.ID
                                    "
                users-by-username-query="SELECT USERNAME,PASSWORD,IS_ACTIVE FROM USER where USERNAME = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="
                                        SELECT ua.USERNAME, a.AUTHORITY_NAME AS AUTHORITY 
                                        FROM USER_AUTHORITIES ua, AUTHORITIES a 
                                        WHERE ua.USERNAME = ? and ua.AUTHORITY_ID = a.ID
                                    " />
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="roleVoter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="roleVoter"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
        <property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
        <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
    </bean>

<bean id="roleHierarchy" class="com.datx.dao.MyRoleHierarchyImpl">
        <property name="roleHierarchyEntryDaoJdbc" ref="RoleHierarchyEntryDaoJdbc" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

---

There are some problems that I cannot find out:
1. I've inserted some pairs like <"URL" , "ROLE"> into URL_ACCESS database. But I'm not sure whether getAttributes method is working fine or not
2. Do I have to implement all those filters that I used in

3. I'm receiving exception when a user uses a wrong username/password or tries to access not-permitted-pages, instead of being redirected to login.jsp. Why is that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this.  Is your application so dynamic that new url are created when using the application that need to be intercepted.  I generally never put anything in a database that only changes with a new development thus a new release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you both Tom and Rob for your quick replies.

First of all, I'm totally aware of "storing url-patterns in database is not a good idea". However we are trying to manage everything dynamically. So there are no other choices.

As it turned out, there were some minor problems with my code.
Here I answer each of my questions one by one.

1. My getAttributes method is working just fine. But there is an alternative to load url-patterns.
   I could load all url-patterns and their corresponding roles first into a HashedMap seperately. And in getAttributes method I could just look up the HasehdMap instead.
   In brief, it'd be like this:

   - HashedMap **url-access** = myDBManager.getAllUrlAccess();
     And in my getAttributes method I use this **url-access** thing.
2. The question is somehow trimmed!
   I was trying to ask about those filters used in springSecurityFilterChain bean.

   ```
   <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
           <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
               <sec:filter-chain pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
               <sec:filter-chain pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
               <sec:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
               <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                   filters="
               securityContextPersistenceFilter,
               logoutFilter,
               authenticationProcessingFilter,
               exceptionTranslationFilter,
               filterSecurityInterceptor" />
           </security:filter-chain-map>
   </bean>
   ```
3. I was receiving exceptions because in authenticationProcessingFilter bean there were no such properties.
   So I re-write it like this:

   ```
   <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
       <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
       <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
       <property name="usernameParameter" value="j_username" />
       <property name="passwordParameter" value="j_password" />
       <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />   
   </bean>
   ```

and of course I had to introduce authenticationFailureHandler bean this as well:

```
<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
</bean>
```

Now I'm not receiving any exceptions.

But here arises another question:
I cannot understand whether username/password is incorrect or the username does not have access to the requested page.
In both cases, the user is redirected according to this bean:

```
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp?error=EntryPoint" />
</bean>
```

Why is it controlling both cases?

Comment: Yes. I have now two different classes for `access denied` and `entry point`. For The former I throw a `403` exception, and for the latter the user is redirected to the page. All I had to do was using another `access denied exception handler`, and handle `403` response by our UI.

Answer (score 4):

First I would ensure you have consulted the [FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-dynamic-url-metadata) about this to ensure you really want to do this. As [tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223376/tom) alluded to, it is generally not advisable to place such information in a database.

In terms of if/why your current code is working it is difficult to say without more details. For example, what are the errors you are seeing in the logs? The question in #2 does not appear to be complete. What do the Spring Security logs say?

If are going to stick with this plan, I would continue to fully use the namespace configuration and [leverage a BeanPostProcessor (as discussed on the FAQ)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-namespace-post-processor) to swap out the `FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource`. An implementation might look something like this:

```
public class FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSourceBeanPostProcessor 
    implements BeanPostProcessor { 
    private FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource;

    public void setMetadataSource(FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource) {
        this.metadataSource = metadataSource;
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) { 
        if(bean instanceof FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource) { 
            return metadataSource; 
        } 
        return bean; 
    } 

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) { 
        return bean; 
    } 
}
```

Then your custom `FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource` could be specified in your Spring configuration along with the `FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSourceBeanPostProcessor`.

```
<bean id="fiMds" class="FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSourceBeanPostProcessor">
  <property name="metadataSource">
    <bean id="myFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource" class="com.datx.dao.MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```